# Reflashing Genesi Efika mx cloud computer

Tags: ubuntu, grub

I was given a genesi efika MX cloud computer which already has ubuntu on it.
But I haven't the admin password or the password for any user.

I cant reset the admin pass because it doesn't seem to have any grub installed (when it boots it shows the genesi logo and then it goes to ubuntu login screen even if I push all the usual keys for accessing the grub menu or a bios such as f1,f2,... shict, del etc)

I tried installing the maveric iso found on their website on an sd card but it wont boot from the card.

Are there any suggestions on how I can access the grub menu or format it?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please read below link to access to GRUB Menu:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/71867/grub-menu-doesnt-appear-when-pressing-shift
Or if you have account on server try below command to reset root password (if sudo installed):

> sudo passwd -

Comment: thx for the answer